# Where to create singleton instance if I don't need this instance in my program?

Tags: c#

Assume I have some singleton that just need to be instantiated. In constructor it starts timer, and updates some model data each second.

To execute singleton constructor I just need to reference it. I don't need resulting instance because I don't need to do anything with singleton it should exist during entire application execution.

However c# doesn't allow such construct: `WcfLoader.Instance;`

So I have to use this `WcfLoader loader = WcfLoader.Instance;` but i never use `loader` instance.

It looks odd, does it mean that I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a static Init method to your class, then call WcfLoader.Init instead of getting an instance. It won't look weird at all.

Comment: In fact, create the Init method like you said and even use it within the singleton's instance property.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I don't think calling init as a side effect of the `Instance` property getter is a good idea.

Comment: Why not?  Just go like `if (_whatever == null) Init(); return _whatever;`

Answer (score 1):

Don't make this a side effect of getting the `Instance` property. Getting a property should not have side effects.

Add a method `InitTimer()` or something like that on the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You could also involve the instance constructor:

```
public class WcfLoader {

   static WcfLoader _instance;

   public WcfLoader() {
      if ( _instance == null ) {
         // do the initialization
         _instance = this; 
      }
   } 
}
```

Then the initialization consist in calling the constructor without even storing the reference anywhere.

```
// just create a new object which causes the initialization code to execute
new WcfLoader();
```

Of course the explicit initialization method (as mentioned by others) is a best choice.